# 1119: Access of possibly undefined property No through a reference with static type Class

Tags: apache-flex

I am creating an Alert box which is giving this error. Please Help: the code is as below:

```
<mx:LinkButton id="deleteButton" visible="false" 
               icon="@Embed('/assets/delete.png')" x="200"  
               toolTip="Delete File" 
               click='Alert.show("Are you sure you want to send the form?","Confirm Delete",Alert.YES | Alert.NO,this,deleteButton_clickHandler,null,Alert.No);'/>
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?  Is it runtime or compile time?

Comment: @www.Flextras.com It is a compile-time error, saying that "No" does not exist on `Alert`... because it doesn't :)  "NO" does.

Comment: @BrianGenisio I assume that is correct; which is why I upvoted your answer.  But, part of my intent on commenting was to push devika to include relevant details as part of their question.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com Agreed.  devika Needed to be more specific AND check his output before posting.  His code was hidden because it wasn't properly formatted with code indenting.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of your Alert call, change `Alert.No` to `Alert.NO`.   (note that "NO" is all caps)